# Passing in command line rules to make

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a makefile with a single rule.  It's so short, it seems a shame to save it to a file:

```
common_defs.h: resources.txt
    ./generate_header.sh common_defs.h resources.txt
```

I would just like to run the generate_header.sh script each time resources.txt is newer than common_defs.h.
It would be nice if I could just pass this rule to make via command-line.  Maybe using make is overkill.  Is there a preferable solution?

Comment: Why would you want to type the whole command to rebuild if you can just type `make`?

Comment: This is third party code which is being configured by my own script.  So the extra characters in the script seem preferable to creating and configuring a makefile outside of the third party codebase.

Comment: That makes sense. It wasn't obvious from the question that you are running this as part of your own script. In that case I fully agree that avoiding `make` makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it.

```
[ resources.txt -nt common_defs.h ] && ./generate_header.sh common_defs.h resources.txt
```

`-nt` is a bash extension to `test` utility for comparing modification times of two files. It's described as below in the man page.

> file1 -nt file2
>
> True if file1 is newer (according to modification date) than file2, or if file1 exists and  file2  does
>                 not.

Comment: in the straightforward case where other make features aren't required, this seems like the obvious solution

Comment: Agreed, thanks pickle-rick for answering the question I asked and to oguz ismail for answering the question I should have asked.

Comment: The `make` solution can be simplified to the point where it isn't significantly more to type than this (and doesn't rely on `bash` extensions).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can pass the rule to make via command-line using `-f -`, in line with the ubiquitous unix practice.

I've wrapped a make target in a shell script before, but for a different purpose -- namely to add a target to an existing makefile.  But, perhaps something like this could be useful to you, which you could embed in a shell script

```
make -f - common_defs.h <<TARGET
common_defs.h: resources.txt
    ./generate_header.sh common-defs.h resources.txt
TARGET
```

Comment: Be sure that's a *tab* that indents the line in the here document, as required by `man`, and not multiple spaces.

Comment: You don't need `cat`; `make -f - common_defs.h <<TARGET` works as the first line.

Comment: Also, rather than specifying a target name, just define the Makefile with a single default target, so that you only need `make -f -`.

Comment: And finally, using `printf` might be simpler to get the formatting right: `printf 'foo: resources.txt\n\t./generate_header.sh common-defs.h resources.txt\n' | make -f -`.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the advice.  I did originally use default target, but added the explicit one just for clarity.  I couldn't immediately see how to maintain the tab in formatting.

Comment: I don't think you can. I usually just use 8 spaces to suggest the tab.